# Concatenate in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i want to browse web pages and i want my intent take a value from EditText

i already declare tf1 as a new EditText and link it with the one in my activity , 
but my problem is in a concatenation My EditText with Uri

here is my code:

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = "http://" + tf1 + " ";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To get text contents out from an `EditText`, call `getText()` to get the `Editable` and call `toString()` on it to make it a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating a string object with an EditText object now. Try replacing `tf1` with `tf1.getText()`.